# jQuery goToByScroll scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, navigation, parallax

I am creating site with parallax using this example: http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html

everything looks ok, but the navigation on the left has annoying bug, when i use navigation steps from top to bottom, everything looks nice, but when using navigation to get back from bottom to top, it can't detect the current slide. Anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Jquery script:

```
$(window).stellar();

//Cache some variables
var links = $('#menu').find('li');
slide = $('.section'); 
mywindow = $(window); 
htmlbody = $('html,body');


//Setup waypoints plugin
slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

    //cache the variable of the data-slide attribute associated with each slide
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

    //If the user scrolls up change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and 
    //remove the active class from the previous navigation link 
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('#menu li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('current').prev().removeClass('current');
    }
    // else If the user scrolls down change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and 
    //remove the active class from the next navigation link

    else {
        $('#menu ul li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('current').next().removeClass('current');
    }



});

//waypoints doesnt detect the first slide when user scrolls back up to the top so we add this little bit of code, that removes the class 
//from navigation link slide 2 and adds it to navigation link slide 1. 
mywindow.scroll(function () {




    if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('#menu li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('current');
        $('#menu li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('current');
    }
});

//Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
//easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.
function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.section[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top-1
    }, 1000, 'easeInOutQuint');
}



//When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

//When the user clicks on the button, get the get the data-slide attribute value of the button and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
/*button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);

});*/
```

So if i add there

`function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
        htmlbody.animate({
            scrollTop: $('.section[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top-1
        }, 1000, 'easeInOutQuint');
    }`

`.offset().top-1` then navigation current menu display bad value when scrooling from top to down, if +1 then bad from down to top, if i leaving just `.offset().top` it shows current page bad from down to top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this same problem by setting a variable 'currentslide', then using this to determine whether the page is scrolling up or down, and offsetting the scroll amount accordingly. So:

```
//Cache some variables
var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
slide = $('.slide');
button = $('.button');
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');
currentslide=1; // new variable to determine current position
```

then lower down:

```
//Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
//easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.
function goToByScroll(dataslide) {

    if (currentslide<dataslide){
        htmlbody.animate({
            scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
        }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
        currentslide=dataslide;
    } else {
        htmlbody.animate({
            scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top -10
        }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
        currentslide=dataslide;
    }

}
```

You may need to adjust the value of -10 depending on your site.